# Finding dynamic elements with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

The application I am automating has a "to..." button that opens up a hovering pop-up that has some selections/options I need to finish filling out the main form.

First, upon pressing the "to..." button, the pop-up "magically" appears, e.g. I do not know what code opens it. The only JavaScript associated with the to_button is:

Once on the new window is open, there is a drop down list where one selects a category from a list box, and after the category is picked the new window is updated with a list of users in that category.

How can I capture the the screen, find out what its names/ids are for the fields and then click its "Done" button (which takes it back to the main screen where "To..." then has the selected values.

Here is the pertinent sections of code:

```
<!-- Recipient List---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <div class="sam-block  clearfix">
        <!-- open selection screen -->
        <div class="label">

            <a style="clear: both;margin-top:5px;" href="#" class="secondaryButtonSmall" id="to_button">To...</a>

        </div>
        <!-- display selected recipients -->
        <div class="field">
            <div id="NotificationRecipientContainer">

            </div>
            <!-- Map ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
            <div id="selectMapLink">

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- hidden window for selection -->
        <div>
            <div id="RecipientSelectionWindow" style="overflow:auto;display:none"><div style="display:inline-block;margin-left:40%;margin-top:20%;"><div class="loadingInline">Loading...</div></div></div><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#RecipientSelectionWindow").kendoWindow({"modal":true,"iframe":false,"draggable":true,"pinned":false,"title":"Send Message To:","resizable":false,"content":null,"width":850,"actions":["Close"]});});
</script>
```

And here is what Selenium(a tool I am not using) came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://connect.blackboardconnect.com/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/Notification/LoadNewMessage?messageStatus=Draft&amp;messageType=Emergency#</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=to_button</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='selectionSourceContent']/div/span/span/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=li.k-item.k-state-hover</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=CAP_523</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Done</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=#CapContent_Tab &gt; a.deliveryModeTabLink.messageChannelChoicesTabLink</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

As a side note, I ran the commands in IRB, and got the following when accessing the security link, and the action failed with the following error:

```
irb(main):055:0> safeButton = browser.link :id => 'safeModeLink'
=> #<Watir::Anchor:0x6a5383a0 located=false selector={:id=>"safeModeLink", :tag_
name=>"a"}>
irb(main):056:0> safeButton.click
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: [JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file:
"file:///C:/Users/TSTURG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20141003-6084-rb5
gxf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js" line: 88
77}]'[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file: "file:///C:/Users/TSTURG~1/AppData/Lo
cal/Temp/webdriver-profile20141003-6084-rb5gxf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.co
m/components/command-processor.js" line: 8877}]' when calling method: [nsIComman
dProcessor::execute]
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:616:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:198:in `switchToDefaultContent'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:76:in `default_content'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/wati
r-webdriver/browser.rb:367:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/wati
r-webdriver/elements/element.rb:532:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/wati
r-webdriver/elements/element.rb:510:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/wati
r-webdriver/elements/element.rb:119:in `click'
        from (irb):56
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It is a bit hard to answer your question without seeing the page. Selenium IDE is making interactions with elements that are not shown in the provided HTML. Is the HTML provided coming from viewing the page source or viewing the current DOM (eg using a developer toolbar, checking the `browser.html`, etc.)?

Comment: This is from the page source. I can get the DOM in the morning EST

Comment: I put together screenshots and a listing of the page source available in the browser (sorry, cannot access the back-end code). How can I get .pdf out for you to look at?

Comment: You could find a place that allows uploading of files and share a link to it.

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/l/AM9OpErW06JD_7DBv3FHykd-ElRL1WrGJ0I/

Comment: Correction:http://www.evernote.com/l/AM_43uDLcLZKxqWRVtFP4msCMrJyO1owWco/

Comment: In the HTML of the PDF file, I do not see the elements that Selenium IDE interacted with. I think you are going to have to find a way to refine the question to be more specific with all the necessary code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I will try to create a little test app and reproduce the issue.